Error Handling error in app router in nextJS14
Tried to use the error boundary handling feature of nextJS in this project. While it redirects to the error component, I get errors on the console.
This is my test component where I force an error.
const session = null;

export default function Home() {
  if (!session) {
    throw new Error("NOT FUCKING WORKING");
  }
  return <main>THIS IS THE MAIN PAGE</main>;
}


This is my error.tsx code
"use client";
import React from "react";

const error = ({}) => {
  return <div>error</div>;
};
export default error;


Now, I am getting the error.tsx UI but getting errors in the console.

redirect-boundary.js:57 Uncaught Error: NOT WORKING
at Home (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/test/page.tsx:11:15)
at e_ (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:264092)
at e (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268224)
at eF (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268712)
at eq (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:274676)
at ej (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:264920)
at e_ (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:263962)
at e (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268224)
at eF (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268712)
at D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:265943
at Array.toJSON (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:266407)
at stringify ()
at eq (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:274775)
at eJ (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:275293)
at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Cherche-Next\cherche\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:265080)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
app-index.js:33 The above error occurred in the  component:

at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:243:11)
at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)
at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)
at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:348:11)
at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:113:9)
at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:160:11)
at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:153:9)
at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:228:11)
at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44)
at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:369:11)
at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:243:11)
at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)
at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)
at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)
at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:348:11)
at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:113:9)
at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:160:11)
at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:153:9)
at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:228:11)
at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:16:44)
at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:369:11)
at div
at body
at html
at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:74:9)
at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:82:11)
at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:76:9)
at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:84:11)
at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:33:11)
at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/ReactDevOverlay.js:87:9)
at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/hot-reloader-client.js:321:11)
at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:207:11)
at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:113:9)
at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:160:11)
at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:577:13)
at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:112:27)
at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:117:11)
at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/ReactDevOverlay.js:87:9)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundaryHandler.
OR IS THIS SUPPOSED TO HAPPEN AND I AM JUST OVERTHINKING.
Tried using useEffect, useState, Custom Hook, try-catch, promise-resolve, then-catch .

Test your app in build, you may not get the UI from the development mode.
Reference

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
